# How do I get multiple items on an address lines to print in Reportlab/tkinter/Python script?

Tags: python, reportlab

How do I get multiple lines to print on one label in reportlab/tkinter/python?  For example, the below prints "Hello" and "World" on two different labels(screenshot attached).  I would like to be able to print "Hello" and "World" on the same label, along with additional items below them that would look something like this:

Hello World

Tomorrow

Wednesday

I have tried adding in the same line(sheet.add_label("Hello", "World") but get attached error.  Any and all help, thoughts, comments appreciated.  Sample working script below:

```
import labels
from reportlab.graphics import shapes

specs = labels.Specification(210, 297, 2, 8, 90, 25, corner_radius=2)

def draw_label(label, width, height, obj):
    label.add(shapes.String(2, 2, str(obj), fontName="Helvetica", fontSize=40))


sheet = labels.Sheet(specs, draw_label, border=True)

sheet.add_label("Hello")
sheet.add_label("World")


sheet.save('basic.pdf')
print("{0:d} label(s) output on {1:d} page(s).".format(sheet.label_count, sheet.page_count))
```

[New Line example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2A6bF.png)

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhSMx.png)

[Original Script Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WNmV.png)

Comment: Check if new lines are printed as \n or correctly with `sheet.add_label("Hello\nWorld")`

Comment: @Daviid it does, with a black box between the words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this problem exists as issue since 2017.

[Long strings don't wrap to new line · Issue #15 · bcbnz/pylabels](https://github.com/bcbnz/pylabels/issues/15)

But you can modify `draw_label` to get list of lines and use two `label.add()` with different position in `String()`

```py
def draw_label(label, width, height, lines):
    #print('lines:', lines)
    label.add(shapes.String(2, 20,  lines[0], fontName="Helvetica", fontSize=20))
    label.add(shapes.String(2, 2, lines[1], fontName="Helvetica", fontSize=20))

sheet = labels.Sheet(specs, draw_label, border=True)

# [ text, text ]
sheet.add_label(["Hello","World"])
```

[image]

You could make it even more complex using list with other values (like `x`, `y`, `fontName`, `fontSize`, etc.)

```py
def draw_label(label, width, height, lines):
    for x, y, text in lines:
        label.add(shapes.String(x, y, text, fontName="Helvetica", fontSize=20))

sheet = labels.Sheet(specs, draw_label, border=True)

# [ (x, y, text), (x, y, text), ... ]
sheet.add_label([ (2, 40, "Hello"), (2, 20, "World"), (2, 2, "Python") ])
```

[image]

---

Full working code

```py
import labels
from reportlab.graphics import shapes

specs = labels.Specification(210, 297, 2, 8, 90, 25, corner_radius=2)

def draw_label(label, width, height, lines):
    for x, y, text in lines:
        label.add(shapes.String(x, y, text, fontName="Helvetica", fontSize=20))

sheet = labels.Sheet(specs, draw_label, border=True)

# [ (x, y, text), (x, y, text), ... ]
sheet.add_label([ (2, 40, "Hello"), (2, 20, "World"), (2, 2, "Python") ])
sheet.add_label([ (2, 40, "Other"), (2, 20, "Label") ])

sheet.save('basic.pdf')

print("{0:d} label(s) output on {1:d} page(s).".format(sheet.label_count, sheet.page_count))
```

[image]

---

**EDIT:**

You could create more complex code to add images

```
sheet.add_label([ 
    ('text', 2, 40, "Hello"), 
    ('text', 2, 20, "World"), 
    ('image', 2, 2, 50, 50, "/home/user/images/logo.png") 
])
```

And it would need to use `if/else` to check `'text'/'image'` and add different `shape`.

Something like this

```
import labels
from reportlab.graphics import shapes

specs = labels.Specification(210, 297, 2, 8, 90, 25, corner_radius=2)

def draw_label(label, width, height, items):
    for item in items:
        if item[0] == 'text':
            print('adding string', item)
            _, x, y, text = item
            label.add(shapes.String(x, y, text, fontName="Helvetica", fontSize=20))
        elif item[0] == 'image':
            print('adding image', item)
            _, x, y, width, heigh, path = item
            label.add(shapes.Image(x, y, width, heigh, path))

sheet = labels.Sheet(specs, draw_label, border=True)

# [ ('text', x, y, text), ('image', x, y, width, height, path), ... ]
sheet.add_label([ ('text', 2, 40, "Hello"), ('text', 2, 20, "World"), ('image', 100, 0, 90, 90 , "/home/furas/images/grass.jpg") ])
sheet.add_label([ ('text', 2, 40, "Other"), ('text', 2, 20, "Label") ])

sheet.save('basic.pdf')

print("{0:d} label(s) output on {1:d} page(s).".format(sheet.label_count, sheet.page_count))
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome @furas!!  I think this will get exactly where I am going!!

Comment: I added example which adds also image to label.

Comment: Thank you so much!!  Quick question, is there a way to determine label size/specs(in script) for Avery 5960 in this instance?  Looking, not having much luck unfortunately.

Comment: I never worked with `Avery 5960` but Google shows me sizes in `inches`: label size: `1" x 2-5/8"` (`1" x 2.625"`), paper size: `8.5" x 11"`. `Specification()` needs values in `millimeters` (`mm`) and `1" = ~25.4mm` and it gives me: label size:`25.4mm x 66.675mm` and paper size `215.9mm x 279.4mm`. It has  3 columns and 10 rows so probably it can `Specification(215.9, 279.4, 3, 10, 66.675, 25.4)`. It seems it has also some margins at top and bottom but I don't know size - so it may need also `Specification(..., top_margin=..., bottom_margin=...)`

Comment: the same `Specification(sheet_width=8.5*25.4, sheet_height=11*25.4, columns=3, rows=10, label_width=2.625*25.4, label_height=1*25.4, top_margin=..., bottom_margin=...)`

Comment: You rock!!  Thanks so much!!

Comment: If I wanted to keep some data on the same line at times, how would I adjust that using the code?

Comment: maybe assign it to variable `same_line = ('text', 2, 40, "Hello")` and use it in all `add_label()` like `sheet.add_label([ same_line, ...])`

Comment: Thank you @furas, that got me going down the right road.  I wound up doing this --same_line = (lname.get() + ", " + fname.get()) and then dropped it in like this --    sheet.add_label([fin, same_line, dob, admit_date], count = 30) which got what I needed.